# Ionic/Angular checkbox custom logic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I am writing a small app in Ionic 2. Within this app i have a "Checkboxmodal" which can create a choice for a list of elements in my appstate.

**In the html:**

```
<ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let key of itemDic.keys()">
        <ion-label>{{itemDic.get(key)}}</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (click)="toggleItem(key)" value="key" [checked]="selectedItems.indexOf(key) > -1"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

**The toggle method:**

```
// Data used
this.itemDic = ... // local. saves possible options
this.selectedItems = ... // reference to appstate (global object). saves the selected values

// toggle function
toggleItem(item: any) {
    if(searchState.contains(...)) {
        searchState.remove(...);
    } else {
        if (this.selectedItems.length >= this.maxItems)
            return;

        searchState.set(...);
    }
}
```

When i wanted to extend its functionality, to only allow x choices at once, i came across the following problem:

- The Databinding seems not to work
- Angular will update the view even if my function did not change the model

How can i:

- stop angular/ionic from changing the view or data
- decide on the model changes on myself
- only display the current value of the data as a binding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just seems, that there is no way to achieve, what i want. I "solved" the problem with another approach:

```
<ion-checkbox 
    (click)="toggleItem(key)" 
    value="key" 
    [disabled]="selectedItems.indexOf(key) === -1 && selectedItems.length >= 3" 
    [checked]="selectedItems.indexOf(key) > -1">
</ion-checkbox>
```

I found out, that you can disable the checkboxes, by binding to the disabled property. So i just check if the current checkbox

- is not checked
- more than the maximum of checkboxes are checked

and disable it, if both are true.

If someone knows a better approach, please post it.